# Who is Onihime talking about in this scene? Is it a 4th wall joke?

Tags: momo-kyun-sword

In Momokyun Sword episode 3, around 12:50, Enki is in the process of "torturing" her prisoner Karin, in a very special way:

Beginning by running her hands up her thighs, telling Karin "私 は 天国 見せて 上げる" - I'll show you heaven.

Then Onihime tells her to stop:

[image: Enki, cut it out or a lot of people will get angry at us]

And Enki promptly stops and apologise, but she is looking straight at the camera angle - probably turning 180° and facing onihime based on their positioning on the shot above.

[image]

But who is this "a lot of people" Onihime mention? It couldn't be anyone from the Earth or Celestial realm, because they are really mad at the oni anyway by default.

It seemed to me that she was breaking the 4th wall. Is it so?

Comment: With the limited information here, yes, I think it is the case.

Comment: I haven't watched this since it originally aired, but from what I remember I agree this is a 4th wall joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subtitles in the screenshot are not exactly accurate. Onihime warns that 「各方面」(*kaku houmen* = all sides, from every quarter) will get 「うるさい」 (*urusai* = noisy, loud, possibly cause a ruckus). It seems that Enki is threatening to rape Karin (from Enki's perspective, it would be heaven, but since Karin is protesting 「いやぁ！やめて！」[*iyaa! yamete!*], that would constitute as non-consensual). Therefore, Onihime warns that everyone would get noisy if Enki went through with it - meaning that either 1) Karin's 「仲間」(*nakama* = comrades, friends) will be indignant about it once they find out, 2) viewers will object with a loud complaint, or 3) the hentai viewers will make some other sort of noise... Her next line recommends for Karin to pray that her *nakama* will arrive soon, so it is very possible that *kaku houmen* refers to them.

It doesn't look like Enki's eyes are looking directly at the camera in the next shot, but rather at Onihime, so no, she does not break the fourth wall.
In summary, Onihime rather than Enki might break the fourth wall by alluding to viewers, but it is not clear enough that she is not referring to an objection by in-canon characters.